# Slow save after changing Core Data relationship validation rule

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, database-migration

This is a strange one. On my data model I created a new version and just modified a relationship to be optional (instead of non-optional)

Running my updated app with a large database created using previous model version will cause the first save to run really slow. This happens after each app launch!

If I build a large database from scratch using my updated app (means, using new model version) there will be no issue.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE 1:
I didn't mention an important fact, which is, the modified relationship (modified from `non-optional` to `optional`) is associated with an image entity holding a large amount of binary data (blob).

So, after adding `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` I figured the following:

- Following the added model version, there is a lightweight migration that rebuilds the image table and re-generate all indexes.
- On the first save this what happens:

  1. `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE`
  2. few `UPDATE`
  3. `COMMIT` (very fast!)
  4. `pragma page_count`
  5. `pragma freelist_count`
  6. `pragma incremental_vacuum(4055)` (very slow, almost 4 seconds!)

`pragma incremental_vacuum` is taking almost 4 seconds on iPhone 6 device and much more time on slower devices (more than 10 seconds).

Note that on the first save, no matter which app you develop, steps 1-5 will always take place after app loaded.

Unique for my case is that I get `incremental_vacuum` in addition. I can see why it's invoked (I guess because there are too many unused pages due to rebuilding the large image table in the lightweight migration phase), however, I can't see why it's invoked later on subsequent app loads.

Shouldn't the first invokation of `incremental_vacuum` fix the issue of unused page and update the sqlite file accordingly? It just seems that the result  of `incremental_vacuum` is kept in memory and not saved to the file (although file is indeed saved)

Comment: Try using Instruments to see exactly where the save is slowing down.

Comment: Tom, thanks for commenting. I used SQL logs instead for now, please see UPDATE 1.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly saving images in core data is not a good practice. Instead you can try saving the images in documents directory and just have their path in the db. Larger size images will considerably slow down the save operation.

Another reason why saves in core data take time are if we are calling the managedObjectContext.save() in a for loop for each entity you are trying to save. Instead insert all the entities and call save() once.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The issue started only after changing the relationship in the data model (from non-optional to optional). I am not running the save in any loop, and anything I save, not just image will take 3-10 seconds just on the first save. Subsequent saves are fine until the next app launch. Something obviously went wrong with the sqlite file, but I can't figure what and why and I have no idea how to debug this...